# PyQt: How to determine, which mouse button is pressed and over which QTableView's cell at the same time?

Tags: python, events, pyqt, mouse, qtableview

I write a PyQt application with `QTableView`, which should insert a new column in response to a left click and delete a column in response to right mouse click on its cells.

What signal should I connect handlers to? If I use [QAbstractItemView.clicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clicked), I can receive the index of column, but can't determine the mouse button, cause it doesn't receive the event.

One the other hand, if I use [QAbstractScrollArea.mousePressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#mousePressEvent), I can get `event.button()`, but it's not clear, how to recover the cell's index.

Qt kinda remind of Schrödinger's indeterminacy here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the state of the mouse buttons with [QApplication.mouseButtons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#mouseButtons):

```
    buttons = QApplication.instance().mouseButtons()
```

With `mousePressEvent`, you can use [QAbstractItemView.indexAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) to get the index:

```
    index = tableview.indexAt(event.pos())
```

Comment: Thanks, ekhumoro. I've overlooked the fact that mousePressEvent is not a signal really, but a function referred to as `signal handler` and it emits `pressed` signal. Should I re-implement mousePressEvent in my QTableView implementation and explicitly emit `pressed` signal from it?

Comment: @Bob. It depends. If you want to keep all the existing functionality of `mousePressEvent`, just call the base-class implementation (i.e. `QTableView.mousePressEvent(self, event)`). However, if you want to suppress some of the existing functionality, you may need to implement some of the other bits yourself (like emitting `pressed`).